# Why does it say index out of bounds when there are two elements in the list and the index is 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pycharm

This is my code:

```py
from tkinter import Label, Button, Tk, Toplevel
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('people.db')
sql = db.cursor()


def person_viewer(person: str) -> None:
    person_viewing_window: Toplevel = Toplevel()
    person_viewing_window.title(person)
    Label(person_viewing_window, text=person).pack()


root: Tk = Tk()
root.title("People")
root.geometry('800x600')
count: int = 0
people: list = []
for person in sql.execute('SELECT first_name FROM people;'):
    people.append(person)
    Button(root, text=person, command=lambda: person_viewer(people[count])).pack()
    count += 1
root.mainloop()
```

I used the debug feature of VS Code to make sure the index really isn't out of bounds and found it wasn't. The index was 1 and the length of the list is 2. That means the second element in the list because of Python's zero-based index. The exact error is below:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\me\Real Documents\people.pyw", line 21, in <lambda>
    Button(root, text=person, command=lambda: person_viewer(people[count])).pack()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As the error indicates, the error only triggers on the click of any of the buttons.

Interestingly, when run in PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2, it gives a quite different error:

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe "C:/Users/me/Real Documents/people.pyw"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/me/Real Documents/people.pyw", line 19, in <module>
    for person in sql.execute('SELECT first_name FROM people;'):
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: people
```

This doesn't occur when run from IDLE, Visual Studio Code, or py.exe.

I don't understand why index is out of bound, and moreover, why PyCharm gives a different, definitely wrong, error. For the record, here's my SQL:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE people (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, first_name TEXT NOT NULL, last_name TEXT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO people VALUES(1,'My','Name');
INSERT INTO people VALUES(2,"Sister's",'Name');

COMMIT;
```

Comment: At the end of your `for` loop, `count` will be equal to the length of the list (and thus out of bounds). Subsequently, when the function you defined, `lambda: person_viewer(people[count]))`, is called, it will give you an out of bounds exception.

Comment: The value of `count` isn't captured when the `lambda` is created. The value of `count` in the `lambda` will be whatever its final value of it was. Since you end that loop with `count += 1`, `count` will be incremented to one past the end of the list as the loop exits, meaning the final value of `count` will be out of bounds.

Comment: @CoolCloud `root: Tk = Tk()` is fine. `:Tk` is a type hint. Also note, the code in your profile can be shortened a bit: `print(''.join(map(chr, [72, 97, 112, 112, 121, 32, 67, 111, 100, 105, 110, 103])))` :)

Comment: @CoolCloud, I prefer using type hints

Comment: Any idea why PyCharm gives a different error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your lambda function to refer to the `person` currently under consideration in your loop, you can copy that value to a dedicated variable inside the lambda function.

A way to do that would be like this:

```
command=(lambda p=person: person_viewer(p))
```

That binds the current value of `person` to the default value of an argument `p` in the function you are defining, and then calls `person_viewer` on that argument.

In context:

```
for person in sql.execute('SELECT first_name FROM people;'):
    people.append(person)
    Button(root, text=person, command=(lambda p=person: person_viewer(p))).pack()
    count += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the `in context` part, that's what I was looking for. Can you tell me why PyCharm gives a different error? I forgot my YouTrack credentials.

Comment: Evidently when your code runs in pycharm it cannot find the `people` table. That is an unrelated problem.

Comment: Why can't Python find the people table when invoked by PyCharm? It's the same interpreter

Comment: I don't know. Try posting a new question about it.

Comment: Issue is on YouTrack [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-44257)